# Website not working when viewed online

Tags: forms, web, size

I have just finished building a website for client, [instantinteriors.com.au](http://instantinteriors.com.au/).  (Visit this site for source code.)

For some reason, when I view the website in Firefox offline as a file it looks like it should. Upon upload the sizing becomes different, such as the font and div sizes. There is also a failure in some of my scripts to operate.

The website appears to work fine in Safari and Chrome, haven't checked on a Windows yet. There also seems to be something wrong with the form, as I have everything ready working and testing, although as soon as it went onto the host server the client uses it fails.

The reason I emphasise client's server is that when I tested it earlier on the host I use it worked fine.

Here is one of many scripts appearing to fail...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $.fn.hasOverflow = function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     var $children = $this.find('*');
     var len = $children.length;

     if (len) {
       var maxWidth = 0;
       var maxHeight = 0
       $children.map(function(){
        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, $(this).outerWidth(true));
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).outerHeight(true));
     });

     return maxWidth > $this.width() || maxHeight > $this.height();
    }

    return false;
    };

  $(function() {
   var $content = $('#wrap4').children().wrapAll('<div>');
   if($content.hasOverflow()){
       $("#arrows").css("display", "none");
   } else {
     $("#arrows").css("display", "block");
   }
 });

 </script>
```

Comment: There is also the problem of, in safari, when I check the blog page which is a feed from the blog showing the latest post, it loads for a second then jumps to showing only the feed from the blog and no webpage.

Comment: You're not giving us much to go on, here.  Also, never program a website on a Mac while hosting it on a Mac.  Doesn't work.  Host it elsewhere, or at the very least, install Apache instead of using raw files.  (Actually, I forget if I used XAMPP last time I programmed a website on Lion; if XAMPP works well, use that.)

Comment: @Zenexer -- what exactly is your reasoning for not developing a website on a Mac? I've found them, by my own experience, to actually be more effective than coding and designing on a Windows machine. (Also, Louis, there's no scrolling for that page in Chrome... so there's a few more issues to note.)

Comment: @Matt Reread what I said.  (I was saying you can program it on a Mac, but I never had much luck actually hosting it on one--I always had issues when I migrated to a Linux server.)

Comment: okay, I put the website up with dreamhost, which doesnt use those public_html folders etc. It worked fine, including the form etc. But when I put it up on bluehost, via their cPanel into the public_html folder it began to lose it.

I realise the scrolling isn't working. As you might see, the scrolling is done by a script to push the div up and down rather than browser controlled scrolling. I will post the script that decides whether the scroll shows or not above.

Comment: @LouisMcSellout Can you give us something more to go on?  Source code snippets or something like that?  You've explained the problem pretty well, yes, but you haven't given us what we need to solve it, or even guide you toward a solution.  Edit: OH I see, you have it on that domain!  Derp.

Comment: @Zenexer -- thank you; that's less ambiguous. Interesting, though. As an aside, I generally have less problems because Mac and Linux run similar Unix cores, whereas Windows gives me problems with line breaks, file paths, DB/PHP/Python configs, permissions, etc.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, you'd think that would be the case--more issues on Windows, which is why I was programming sites on Mac for a while--but amazingly, I had a lot of similar issues on Mac.  I'm checking out the source code now to see if I can find anything.  Nice site, by the way, Louis!

Comment: @LouisMcSellout You might want to take a closer look at the fonts on Windows; be sure to zoom in all the way http://i.imgur.com/FgjUK.png (side note)

Comment: I don't know: it all looks to be in order to me, except the fonts (which are even worse than that screenshot elsewhere--some text is illegible).

Comment: @LouisMcSellout What is the `mousehold` function you are trying to call?  Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/ZGh4x.png  There are only two JS files included on the page.  I something missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your logic correct? Your `hasOverflow` function returns true when either your maxWidth or maxHeight is greater than your current width and height. If you have overflow shouldn't the test be if either the current values are greater than the maximums?

You should switch the way you use the `hasOverflow` result so the arrows are shown when you have overflow. You can use the `show()` and `hide()` methods as shorthand.

```
if($content.hasOverflow()) {
  $("#arrows").show();
} else {
  $("#arrows").hide();
}
```

Is this being called when the document is ready? The source formatting makes it hard to tell.

Comment: This didn't work. Changed the logic etc. And it made it work on less browsers.

Comment: Ok, changed a few extra things, with your advice included and seems to work fine now. Not sure exactly what the issue was, possibly the styling.